# How to get memory address from file path without opening file

Tags: c, windows, filesystems

I have a file. I know its file path, and I want to know its memory address. My problem is that I can't actually open the file (fopen can't be used because the OS thinks the file is in use) to get its memory address.

Ex.
`fopen("C:/example/file", "r")` returns null

From why I understand the OS returns the memory address after it confirms the file isn't in use. So is it even possible to bystep the OS?

Comment: Files don't have "memory addresses", so it's extremely unclear what you're asking. `fopen()` opens the file and returns a **FILE pointer**.

Comment: A file in use can be opened, depending on the locks placed on it by any of the processes that open the file.  Do you know if its locked for shared read?

Comment: @Ken White, maybe I have the terminology wrong, I'm trying to find the location of a file in memory.

Comment: @Grantly, there's an exclusive lock on it, that's all I could figure out

Comment: That's the part that doesn't make sense. Files don't have "locations in memory" until you successfully open them and read the content. Before that point, they're not "in memory".

Comment: Files are essentially NOT in memory.  They are on a disk or catalog of some sort, and memory has no idea that they are there.  When they are loaded into memory, thats a different story - then theie contents is in memory and the file is also still on the disk.  The physical position that the file starts at, is usually relatively unchanged (except it does change in many circumstances), but its a physical storage address.  The file contents in memory could have pretty much any random address - memory address that is.

Comment: @Alter exclusive locks are difficult to bypass.  You might have to tackle your problem any way...What do you want with the 'address'?

Comment: I see, could I write code that loads the file into memory? I suppose I would have to find it first, which would be difficult. On the other hand, perhaps it's already in memory (if I try to copy + paste the file, it says it's already open in System)

Comment: @Grantly I wanted the address so I could copy its bytes into another file that I can open. Maybe I can copy the bytes in the physical address?

Comment: If the file is exclusively opened by another process, there's not way to open it to load it into memory. "Exclusively" means "for me only - I'm not sharing it with you". You can't access it any other way than opening it, and if opening it has been expressly denied then you're wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

@Alter by finding the `Process ID` of the process that has locks on the file, you could get somewhere...  You might be able to track your files contents in memory as part of the memory space allocated to the Process.

However, just because a file is locked does not at all mean that the file is in memory.  Sometimes just a part of a file is used, like the functions within a DLL - where only the 'used' and necessary chunks of the file would be in memory.  Other times, the entire document (file) will be present very nicely and contiguously in memory (consider a text file open in Notepad) .  It is also possible that the file is locked purely like a placeholder, where the lock is all that matters and none of the file is actually loaded.  You really need to know alot about the Process that has locks on the file.

Now if you simply want to copy the file to another file, then launch the copy before the 'Process' locks the file.  You could try a batch file that runs at Windows Startup - and see if that is early enough to copy the file before a lock is placed on it.